# How to check if internet connection from is proxy is lost or present?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, proxies

I am building a Selenium bot and have to use that script multiple times in a go. The problem with the script is that the proxy I am using rotated itself in every 10-12 mins and when it rotates, the internet connection is lost for 10-15 seconds which results in either freezing of the page or breaking the code.

I want to check the internet connection from proxy at every step in my script, if that is present, I will move forward and if not, I will wait for some 30 sec so the connection is automatically restored.

Is there any way I can check the connection?
or any other better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: You do know that you can programatically set proxy if you are using a geckodriver?

Comment: I am not using a geckodriver and I did not know that, I am bound to use chrome driver

Answer (score 0):

You could you [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) to check the internet connection.

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Or you could use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to check the response code if there’s connection or not.